# Why is this Javascript command to alter css id not working?

Tags: javascript, css

I was trying to set a background image for my `PicInner` css class but it wasn't working, so I'm trying to just even change the background color:

```
function changeBackground()
{
    $('.PicInner').css('background', 'orange');
}
```

I've tried it without the `.` for the class selector but that doesn't work either. What could be overriding this?

I know the function is being called because I inserted an `Alert("Hello!");` line and it pops up every time I refresh the page, but the background colour of my `.PicInner` class just doesn't change. I've changed the background in the F12 editor on my `PicInner` class and it works fine, just the javascript doesn't seem to be changing anything for me.

Where could I be going wrong?

The relevant html section is

```
<script>

    changeBackground();

    function changeBackground()
    {
        alert("HELLO!");
        ('.PicInner').css('background', 'orange');
    }
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/CJBStyles.css">

<div class="wContainer">
    <div class="cjb-bkg">
        <div class="PicInner">
            <h3>Bespoke Kitchens, bathrooms and fittings</h3>
            <h3>Prestigious and high quality</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css for PicInner is:

```
.PicInner{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: where/when do you call the `changeBackground` function ? Do you have jQuery loaded ? Can you show the relevant html ?

Comment: Is it `picInner` or `PicInner`? Perhaps a typo in case? If not, what does `alert($('.PicInner').length)` say?

Comment: because you use  jQuery code, and you didn't have any vanila javascript ?

Comment: I'm not using jQuery - is the `$().css()` jQuery and not plain javascript? I'm a total js noob - I've only done c# and loads of backend stuff so all the different js frameworks are completely lost on me.

Comment: I've added the html and css parts, this html is a partial view within a c# mvc project - I was worried the code wasn't even being called, hence why I added the ALERT which is definitely working

Comment: yes this is jQuery and not plain javascript and you may have a css hierarchy that cause your dysfunction

Comment: I tried adding jQuery via the MS CDN `<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>` but it still doesn't work. I will try this on my default `.css` page to see if heirarchy is causing the issue.

Comment: after adding the jQuery, instead of just `changeBackground();` to call it use `$(function(){ changeBackground(); });` because the function needs to be called after the DOM has been loaded. Otherwise the element does not yet exist when you call the function so nothing is done.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli yup, that fixed it. I've seen this instructed many times before but never even considered it here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function fired on "Page loaded" event:

```js
function changeBackground() {
  var elm = document.querySelector('.PicInner');
  elm.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'
}

changeBackground();
```

```css
.PicInner {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wContainer">
  <div class="cjb-bkg">
    <div class="PicInner">
      <h3>Bespoke Kitchens, bathrooms and fittings</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There can not be  tag in the snippet, but I will let you know that, in a "real" web page, you can explicitly fire `changeBackground()` on page load:

```
<body onload="changeBackground()">
```

Comment: i do not see anything related to "page loaded" in that code. Also no need to post two answers, you can add multiple solutions to a single answer.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I have just made a reference to "page loaded". Thanks for the observation.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir thanks, this works great and I've accepted it because it does answer my question. I do have a big issue now, which is that the html I'm running this in is a partial file, which means the "body" element can't be used in it. And I don't really want to put my `body onload="changebackground"` in the shared layout html when its only relevant to this single page... can I used other elements loading to trigger this function?

Comment: Never mind, I found `window.onload` elsewhere and this does the trick! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your main problem seems to stem from the confusion about what `$('.PicInner')` does. This expression does NOT return the CSS class itself. Rather, it searches for all the HTML elements that have this class - **at that point in time** - and returns a collection (something similar to an array, but with extra methods) of those. And then when you do `.css('background', 'orange')` you're actually setting the `style` property on each of them individually. You're **NOT** modifying the CSS class itself.

With that in mind, the reason why your code doesn't do anything becomes obvious - the document is loaded and code is executed in sequence. At the time when you're executing this code, the HTML element with `class="PicInner"` isn't yet loaded. So nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes total sense. I've accepted another answer because he provided code and actually helps me avoid jQuery altogether but this is very informative.

Comment: @jamheadart - Fair enough. :) Btw - also consider using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `<body onload="..">` and the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event. :)

Comment: Yeah I ended up using `window.onload` but did see eventListeners on my travels, either way there are plenty of options - now it's just figuring out why and which is the best one :D

Comment: @jamheadart - `addEventListener` has the advantage of attaching multiple handlers to a single event. Thus you won't come into conflict with other libraries that want to attach to the same event. `DOMContentLoaded` is nice because it fires much sooner that `load`. You're still guaranteed that all the HTML is there, but you don't need to wait for the CSS and images to load. Most of the time that's enough and it creates a better, snappier user experience (you can start using the page sooner).

Comment: Yeah I like the idea of DOMContentLoaded as opposed to the entire page. That'd mean I can effectively change content, images, colours etc. before it's even showing on the screen. Thanks for the advice, I will be trying both methods to see how they go.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery selectors, you must include the jQuery library. Else, you can use plain JavaScript (and I advise you to do so).

Also, you have to run your function, on an event (I see you have edited your question and are now running your function `onload`):

```js
function changeBackground() {
  var elm = document.querySelector('.PicInner');
  elm.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'
}
```

```css
.PicInner {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wContainer">
  <div class="cjb-bkg">
    <div class="PicInner">
      <h3>Bespoke Kitchens, bathrooms and fittings</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="changeBackground()">Run function!!!</button>
```

Above, your function is run ("fired") upon clicking a button.

Comment: Well this makes sense, after a comment by @GrabrielePetrioli I've realised I need this fired on a "Page loaded" event!

Comment: But yes I think I'm going to alter my method to use plain javascript. I hate having to keep adding more plug-ins and references to add-ons and frameworks. To be honest, I was trying to do a carousel without even using javascript in the first place but it got too convoluted.